# Customizing Theme My Login widget on wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

I'm currently having a problem customizing the look of the Theme My Login widget, I am using the Parabola theme. At the moment it looks like this:

[Current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNSYJ.png)

But I would like to have the links be to the right of the avatar instead of under it. I have resized both the avatar and user links areas so that they are the correct size to fit next to each other in the widget space but I am unsure how to get it to sit next to the avatar now.

Here is the code I used to resize them:

```
.avatar.avatar-100.photo{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.tml-user-links{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

And here is the code for the widget:

```
<?php
/**
 * Holds the Theme My Login widget class
 *
 * @package Theme_My_Login
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'Theme_My_Login_Widget' ) ) :
/*
 * Theme My Login widget class
 *
 * @since 6.0
 */
class Theme_My_Login_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @since 6.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_options = array(
            'classname'   => 'widget_theme_my_login',
            'description' => __( 'A login form for your blog.', 'theme-my-login' )
        );
        parent::__construct( 'theme-my-login', __( 'Theme My Login', 'theme-my-login' ), $widget_options );
    }

    /**
     * Displays the widget
     *
     * @since 6.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $args Display arguments including before_title, after_title, before_widget, and after_widget.
     * @param array $instance The settings for the particular instance of the widget
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        $theme_my_login = Theme_My_Login::get_object();

        $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, array(
            'default_action'      => 'login',
            'logged_in_widget'    => true,
            'logged_out_widget'   => true,
            'show_title'          => true,
            'show_log_link'       => true,
            'show_reg_link'       => true,
            'show_pass_link'      => true,
            'show_gravatar'       => true,
            'gravatar_size'       => 50
        ) );

        // Show if logged in?
        if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! $instance['logged_in_widget'] )
            return;

        // Show if logged out?
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! $instance['logged_out_widget'] )
            return;

        $args = array_merge( $args, $instance );

        echo $theme_my_login->shortcode( $args );
    }

    /**
    * Updates the widget
    *
    * @since 6.0
    * @access public
    */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['default_action']      = in_array( $new_instance['default_action'], array( 'login', 'register', 'lostpassword' ) ) ? $new_instance['default_action'] : 'login';
        $instance['logged_in_widget']    = ! empty( $new_instance['logged_in_widget'] );
        $instance['logged_out_widget']   = ! empty( $new_instance['logged_out_widget'] );
        $instance['show_title']          = ! empty( $new_instance['show_title'] );
        $instance['show_log_link']       = ! empty( $new_instance['show_log_link'] );
        $instance['show_reg_link']       = ! empty( $new_instance['show_reg_link'] );
        $instance['show_pass_link']      = ! empty( $new_instance['show_pass_link'] );
        $instance['show_gravatar']       = ! empty( $new_instance['show_gravatar'] );
        $instance['gravatar_size']       = absint( $new_instance['gravatar_size'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
    * Displays the widget admin form
    *
    * @since 6.0
    * @access public
    */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'default_action'      => 'login',
            'logged_in_widget'    => 1,
            'logged_out_widget'   => 1,
            'show_title'          => 1,
            'show_log_link'       => 1,
            'show_reg_link'       => 1,
            'show_pass_link'      => 1,
            'show_gravatar'       => 1,
            'gravatar_size'       => 50,
            'register_widget'     => 1,
            'lostpassword_widget' => 1
        );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, $defaults );

        $actions = array(
            'login'        => __( 'Login',         'theme-my-login' ),
            'register'     => __( 'Register',      'theme-my-login' ),
            'lostpassword' => __( 'Lost Password', 'theme-my-login' )
        );

        echo '<p>' . __( 'Default Action', 'theme-my-login' ) . '<br /><select name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'default_action' ) . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'default_action' ) . '">';
        foreach ( $actions as $action => $title ) {
            $is_selected = ( $instance['default_action'] == $action ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            echo '<option value="' . $action . '"' . $is_selected . '>' . $title . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['logged_in_widget'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'logged_in_widget' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'logged_in_widget' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'logged_in_widget' ) . '">' . __( 'Show When Logged In', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['logged_out_widget'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'logged_out_widget' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'logged_out_widget' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'logged_out_widget' ) . '">' . __( 'Show When Logged Out', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['show_title'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'show_title' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_title' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_title' ) . '">' . __( 'Show Title', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['show_log_link'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'show_log_link' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_log_link' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_log_link' ) . '">' . __( 'Show Login Link', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['show_reg_link'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'show_reg_link' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_reg_link' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_reg_link' ) . '">' . __( 'Show Register Link', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['show_pass_link'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'show_pass_link' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_pass_link' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_pass_link' ) . '">' . __( 'Show Lost Password Link', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        $is_checked = ( empty( $instance['show_gravatar'] ) ) ? '' : 'checked="checked" ';
        echo '<p><input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'show_gravatar' ) . '" type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_gravatar' ) . '" value="1" ' . $is_checked . '/> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'show_gravatar' ) . '">' . __( 'Show Gravatar', 'theme-my-login' ) . '</label></p>' . "\n";

        echo '<p>' . __( 'Gravatar Size', 'theme-my-login' ) . ': <input name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'gravatar_size' ) . '" type="text" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_size' ) . '" value="' . $instance['gravatar_size'] . '" size="3" /> <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_size' ) . '"></label></p>' . "\n";
    }
}
endif; // Class exists
```

If anyone can guide me on how to do this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: try to add `float:left` to the image. You can also try to set margin, and padding to 0.

Comment: It didn't have any effect. Setting margin and padding to 0 also had no effect.

Comment: add a background-color (with different colors) to see the size of your elements and if they are really blocks.

Comment: Just checked, they are both blocks and they are both the correct size.

Comment: Casimir, if you want to add an answer I'll accept it, seeing as it was you who put me on the right track to get it done.

Comment: Thanks, but It was only an idea, I'm not a css guru and I assume there are probably better, more elegant, more waterproof more simple ways to do that. You should ask a question using the css tag about the way to do that and with all the css rules related to your elements (including more general rules that apply to each img, link...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through enough tinkering I have managed to figure out the solution. I had to change the code to this:

```
.avatar.avatar-100.photo{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.tml-user-links{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

A big thank you to Casimir et Hippolyte for putting me on the right track.

The widget now looks like this:

[Current widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPLs2.png)

I still would like to center the links a little bit, but I'm sure I can tinker enough until I figure it out again. Figured I would add the answer to the post in case anyone runs in to the same problem in the future.

**EDIT:**

I have finally gotten it exactly how I want it. `Using margin-right: 120px;` under `.tml-user-links`

Here is the final result:

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yuy3.png)